# ContextMenu in GMap primefaces component

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, primefaces, primefaces-gmap

Does anybody know how to create a primefaces contextmenu that will be launched on right click on GMap?

Normally the code should look like this:

```
<p:gmap id="gmapElement" widgetVar="gmtls" center="41.381542, 2.122893" zoom="15" type="hybrid" styleClass="mapClass"/>
<p:contextMenu for="gmapElement" >  
    <p:menuitem value="Method A" onclick="method1()" />  
    <p:menuitem value="Method B" onclick="method2()" />  
</p:contextMenu>
```

However, google api overrides right click event. I think that the best way to handle it is additional listener in google map. But I cannot find any information how to show the context menu programatically:

```
var mapComponent = gmtls.getMap();
google.maps.event.addListener(mapComponent, 'rightclick', function(mouseEvent) {
    //show context menu at coordinates: mouseEvent.latLng
});
```

Can someone tell me what should I put in the listener body?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16446515/1834700

Comment: If you have found your answer, you should post as answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is the answer I was looking for. During initialisation of GMap component additional listener in google maps API must be registered:

```
var mapComponent = gmtls.getMap();
google.maps.event.addListener(mapComponent, 'rightclick', function(mouseEvent) {
    $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('mainForm:contextMenu')).css({
        top: yPos+'px',
        left: xPos+'px'                        
    }).show();
});
```

The easiest way to get coordinates (yPos, xPos) is to use jQuery which listen on mouseMove event:

```
var xPos = 0;
var yPos = 0;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        xPos = e.pageX;
        yPos = e.pageY;
    }); 
})
```